# Working out probability distribution from given uniform random variable

Tags: probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

[image]

I'm not able to understand how they got from probability U is less than e to the power of x to e^-x? shouldn't it be e^x instead because we are given in our notes that probability U that's less than u is = u so probability u is less than e to the power of x should be should be = e^x and not e^-x? Also, for the line after that how did they get e^mod x? What exactly are we considering when we consider the case when x<0 and when x>0.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It should be $e^x$, this is a typo. ($\mathbb{P}\{U \leq e^x\} = e^x = e^{-\lvert x\rvert}$)

Comment: hmm also if $log U \leq 0$, shouldn't $P(\log U \leq x) = 1$ and not $0$ for $x > 0$?

Comment: ok once we have e^x, how do we get to e^-mod x, which is the last step that I'm not getting.

Comment: since $x<0$, hence a negative number, $x=-|x|$.